# How to select just one item from listview

Tags: listview, vb6

Using Listview with Checkbox

ListView

```
checkbox id

001
002
003
...
```

I want to select only one id at a time, and i want to show a selected item in the messagebox

for example

`001` id is checked, if i check `002` id means automatically `001` id check should remove, and display a messagebox "002 is Selected"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a ListBox, the default behaviour is for only one item to be selected at a time. You can change that behaviour by setting or clearing the `.MultiSelect` property.

[Here](http://www.vbexplorer.com/VBExplorer/vb_feature/june2000/june2000.asp) is a tutorial you may find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using a ListView, you will need to go through every other item and make sure it's unchecked when a new item is checked.

Answer (score 0):

When the first checkbox is clicked, record a reference in a variable somewhere. When any other checkbox is clicked uncheck the old one by reference, and store a reference to the new one. Much more efficient than looping through everything.