# How to check the only one checkbox in the ListView

Tags: vb6

I have n number of items in the listview, if i select checkbox box all other checkbox should removed automatically.

Code

```
Dim count, idx As Integer
    count = 0
    For idx = 1 To lvwMedia.ListItems.count
        If lvwMedia.ListItems(idx).Checked Then
            lvwMedia.ListItems(idx).Checked = False
        End If
    Next
```

The above code is working, but in which event i have to write the above code.

Comment: possible duplicate of your previous question [How to select just one item from listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471295/how-to-select-just-one-item-from-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ItemCheck event is what you are looking for. Here is the appropriate code.

```
Private Sub lvwMedia_ItemCheck(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim bln As Boolean

    bln = lvwMedia.ListItems(Item.Index).Checked

    For idx = 1 To lvwMedia.ListItems.count
        If lvwMedia.ListItems(idx).Checked Then
            lvwMedia.ListItems(idx).Checked = False
        End If
    Next

    lvwMedia.ListItems(Item.Index).Checked = bln
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used VB6, but maybe try the ItemCheck event.

Edit - Also, regarding your algorithm, I'd recommend against using a loop to un-check everything. Instead, when the ItemCheck event gets triggered record the current item that is selected and un-check the last item that was selected. That way instead of looping through everything every time you never have to loop through anything, which is faster.